# Sub query in the where clause

Tags: sql, sql-server

The code below is working now in the **VIEW** based on **Windows Authentication**, users should able to see all the data that they own and data of those reports to them direct or indirect.  Now another WHERE clause needed to handle the additional result of data that giving to the user in the Authorize column.

SAMPLE DATA: Table TORGANIZATION_HIERARCHY

```
    ManagerID | ManagerEmail    | Email             | EmployeeID | Authorize |  Level
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    NULL      | NULL            | user0@@abc.com    | 1     | NULL           |  0
    1         | user0@@abc.com  | user1@@abc.com    | 273   | NULL           |  1
    273       | user1@@abc.com  | user2@@abc.com    | 16    | NULL           |  2
    273       | user1@@abc.com  | SJiang@@abc.com   | 274   | NULL           |  2
    273       | user1@@abc.com  | SAbbas@abc.com    | 285   | user2@@abc.com; user3@abc.com |  2
    285       | SAbbas@abc.com  | LTsoflias@abc.com | 286   | NULL           |  3
    274       | SJiang@@abc.com | MBlythe@abc.com   | 275   | NULL           |  3
    274       | SJiang@@abc.com | LMitchell@abc.com | 276   | NULL           |  3
    16        | JWhite@abc.com  | user3@abc.com     | 23    | NULL           |  3
```

SAMPLE DATA: Table TRANS

```
    Email             | Destination_account      | Customer_service_rep_code   
    -----------------------------------------------------------
    SAbbas@abc.com    |   Philippines            | 12646
    Junerk@abc.com    |   Canada                 | 95862
    LTsoflias@abc.com |   Italy                  | 98524
    user2@@abc.com    |   Italy                  | 29185
    user3@@abc.com    |   Brazil                 | 58722
```

The bottom query is working when user SAbbas@abc.com (285) log in.  It can see all the data of EmployeeID 285 and 286.  I need add another where statement that user (**SAbbas@abc.com**) authorized to see to see in column Authorize. So the result user SAbbas@abc.com should see EmployeeID 285, 286, 16, 23.

```
WITH CTE 
 AS (SELECT OH.employeeid, 
            OH.managerid, 
            OH.email AS EMPEMAIL, 
            1        AS level 
     FROM   TORGANIZATION_HIERARCHY OH 
     WHERE  OH.[email] = (SELECT SYSTEM_USER)  --Example SAbbas@abc.com
     UNION ALL 
     SELECT CHIL.employeeid, 
            CHIL.managerid, 
            CHIL.email, 
            level + 1 
     FROM   TORGANIZATION_HIERARCHY CHIL 
            JOIN CTE PARENT 
              ON CHIL.[managerid] = PARENT.[employeeid]), 
 ANOTHERCTE 
 AS (SELECT   
    T.[email], 
    T.[destination_account], 
    T.[customer_service_rep_code] 
     FROM   [KGFGJK].[DBO].[TRANS] AS T) 

   SELECT * 
   FROM   ANOTHERCTE 
   INNER JOIN CTE 
           ON CTE.empemail = ANOTHERCTE.[email];
```

Comment: I have no idea what your question is.

Comment: @newbie, i don't see in the table what would allow SAbbas to see data of employees 285, 286, 16, 23? a little bit more information would help

Comment: Your question (or lack thereof ) is confusing. The Employees 16 and 23 have no reference to the `Authorize` column or the Emails inside of it. Are you confusing Employee and Manager ID's?. Why not just add an `OR` condition for `OR Authorize = (SELECT From SYSTEM_USER)`. Again I'm assuming. No idea what you want...

Comment: @zip I have added another the table name **TRANS** I hope it helps with my question.  Again, the current query is working now if user SAbbas@abc.com log in, he should see the two records in TRANS table one is his **SAbbas@abc.com** and other **LTsoflias@abc.com** that report to him.  I also expect him to see more records in **TRANS** table, where he permits to see in **Authorize** column of table **TORGANIZATION_HIERARCHY**, this is where I cannot get it to works.  I hope the question much clearer now.

Comment: @Matt, please see the above comment.  Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will give you what you need based on column Authorize. The result should be 16 and 23

```
Select b.employeeid from TORGANIZATION_HIERARCHY a inner join TORGANIZATION_HIERARCHY b
on a.Authorize like  '%' + b.Email + '%'
where a.Email = 'SAbbas@abc.com'
```

Let me know

**Complete Solution:**

For you to be able to see user3@abc.com, I had to correct the email in 6the table #TRANS. You worte in there user3@@abc.com instead of user3@abc.com. @ and not @@.
the code is below for your tests. After you can replace with you table names

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#TORGANIZATION_HIERARCHY') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #TORGANIZATION_HIERARCHY;   


    select  NULL  as ManagerID    ,NULL as ManagerEmail           ,'user0@@abc.com'  as Email  ,1 as EmployeeID    ,NULL    as Authorize       , 0 as Level into #TORGANIZATION_HIERARCHY
    union select    1         ,'user0@@abc.com',  'user1@@abc.com'    ,273   ,NULL           , 1
    union select    273       ,'user1@@abc.com',  'user2@@abc.com'    ,16    ,NULL           , 2
    union select    273       ,'user1@@abc.com',  'SJiang@@abc.com'   ,274   ,NULL           , 2
    union select    273       ,'user1@@abc.com',  'SAbbas@abc.com'    ,285   ,'user2@@abc.com; user3@abc.com' , 2
    union select    285       ,'SAbbas@abc.com',  'LTsoflias@abc.com' ,286   ,NULL           , 3
    union select    274       ,'SJiang@@abc.com', 'MBlythe@abc.com'   ,275   ,NULL           , 3
    union select    274       ,'SJiang@@abc.com', 'LMitchell@abc.com' ,276   ,NULL           , 3
    union select    16        ,'JWhite@abc.com',  'user3@abc.com'  ,23    ,NULL           , 3

    --select * from #TORGANIZATION_HIERARCHY

IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#TRANS') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #TRANS;   

    select 'SAbbas@abc.com'  as Email ,    'Philippines'  as Destination_account         ,  12646 as Customer_service_rep_code into #TRANS
    union select 'Junerk@abc.com'   ,    'Canada'                ,  95862
    union select 'LTsoflias@abc.com',    'Italy'                 ,  98524
    union select 'user2@@abc.com'   ,    'Italy'                 ,  29185
    union select 'user3@abc.com'   ,    'Brazil'                ,  58722

    ;WITH CTE 
     AS (SELECT OH.employeeid, 
                OH.managerid, 
                OH.Authorize, 
                OH.email AS EMPEMAIL, 
                1        AS [level] 
         FROM   #TORGANIZATION_HIERARCHY OH 
         WHERE  OH.[email] = (SELECT 'SAbbas@abc.com')  --Example
         UNION ALL 
         SELECT CHIL.employeeid, 
                CHIL.managerid, 
                CHIL.Authorize, 
                CHIL.email, 
                CHIL.[level] + 1 
         FROM   #TORGANIZATION_HIERARCHY CHIL 
                JOIN CTE PARENT 
                  ON CHIL.[managerid] = PARENT.[employeeid]), 
     ANOTHERCTE 
     AS (SELECT   
        T.[email], 
        T.[destination_account], 
        T.[customer_service_rep_code] 
         FROM   #TRANS AS T) 

       SELECT *
       FROM   ANOTHERCTE 
       RIGHT JOIN 
       (
            select a.EmployeeID, a.ManagerID, a.Authorize, a.Email as empemail, a.[level] From CTE INNER JOIN #TORGANIZATION_HIERARCHY a on lower(CTE.Authorize) like  '%' + lower(a.Email) + '%'
            union
            select * From CTE 
       ) CTE
               ON CTE.empemail = ANOTHERCTE.[email]
    order by [level]
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: per your suggestion, I added the code to the original query (see below) but still get only SAbbas@abc.com and LTsoflias@abc.com records from TRANS table.  I expect to get records related to email address SAbbas@abc.com, LTsoflias@abc.com, user2@@abc.com and user3@abc.com from TRANS table. 
 `WITH CTE AS (SELECT OH.employeeid, OH.managerid, OH.email AS EMPEMAIL, 1        AS level FROM   TORGANIZATION_HIERARCHY OH INNER JOIN TORGANIZATION_HIERARCHY B ON OH.Authorize like  '%' + B.Email + '%' WHERE  OH.[email] = 'SAbbas@abc.com' UNION ALL SELECT CHIL.employeeid`..........

Comment: hi @Newbie, I have posted the full solution for you to see and the result giving 285, 286, 16 and 23. hope it helps

Comment: thank you @zip for your help.  I was able to try it out and it works.  I don't even realize the typo until you pointed out :).  Thank you so much.